# Passing local variable to directive in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a controller that feed a repeater with an array:

```
demo.controller('MyCntl', function ($scope, $compile) {

    $scope.items = [
        { name: 'Diego' },
        { name: 'Darko' }
    ];       

    $scope.load = function (obj) {            
        $('body').append($compile("<panel data='obj'  />")($scope));
    }

});

<div ng-controller='MyCntl'>    
    <p ng-repeat='item in items'>
        <button ng-click='load(item)'>Load {{item.name}}</button>
    </p>       
</div>
```

and as you can see, the repeated item has a button to load further data. When button is clicked it calls the load(obj) function, that append to the page a directive:

```
demo.directive('panel', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data: '@'
        },
        template: '<pre>I\'m a panel called by {{data.name}}</pre>',
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

        }            
    }
});
```

The problem is that I can't understand how to pass the local variable **obj** to the directive. I know I could set the variable to the $scope of the controller and read it easily from the directive, but it would be kinda defeat.

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/darkoromanov/cngd9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can create new scope to put your local variables in.
In your case you have to make two changes:

1) If you use '@' in the Directive then you can only pass String, if you want to pass an object use '='.

```
scope: {  
    data: '='  
},
```

2) In the controller create the new scope

```
var newScope = $scope.$new();  
newScope.obj = obj;  
$('body').append($compile("<panel data='obj'  />")(newScope));
```

Comment: nice! The weird thing is that the new scope is still linked with $scope even if I create it this way: var newScope = $scope.$new(true); It's ok, but I wonder why.

Comment: Yes, you are right the signature of this method is  
    $new(isolate)
And isolate is a boolean. Documentation says:  
"If true, then the scope does not prototypically inherit from the parent scope."

Answer (score 1):

you can pass variable as attribute of element but it should be an attribute of your current scope so,
I made a few changes to your code

```
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        $scope.data = $scope.$eval($attrs.data);     
    }
```

and here is my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wickY26/5ZBAe/1/) take a look is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer and the Fiddle. Well yes, it works but it doesn't pass the local variable. If I won't find any other ways I'll use your code.

Answer (score 1):

Using DOM manipulation in controller is not ideal so I would recommend the other way to achieve this.

I would maintain a collection for panels as

```
$scope.panels = [];
$scope.load = function (obj) {
    $scope.panels.push(obj);
};
```

And render it in HTML directly:

```
<panel data="{{panel.name}}" ng-repeat="panel in panels track by $index"  />
```

Finally change the directive slightly:

```
demo.directive('panel', function () {
   return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        data: '@'
      },
      template: '<pre>I\'m a panel called by {{data}}</pre>'        
  }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cngd9/1/

Comment: Yeah, I'm not happy at all with DOM manipulation in controllers, but I'm not so sure I'd be happy to have all my modal popups inside the index.html. I'm developing a CMS so I have many templates and many directives, I prefer to load the templates via ajax because in this way I can organize them on filesystem, rather than have them all in a unique file that would grow too much too easily. Maybe a solution could be using server side inclusion.

Comment: If I understood you correctly then in that case you should use `templateUrl` instead of `template` to load markups asynchronously.

Comment: exactly, I already use that, but for the sake of simplicity I used inline html for the example.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your fiddle. See here

http://jsfiddle.net/BDrCr/

The problem is that you cannot pass parameter to directive which is not bound to scope. In your case `obj`. I have also change the scope property to use `=`.

So the scope load method changes to

```
  $scope.load = function (obj) {
        var index=$scope.items.indexOf(obj);
        $('body').append($compile("<panel data='items["+ index +  "]'/>")($scope));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand the problem. Also good point the "=" to the scope.